# Firebug: is there a Break On Next keyboard shortcut?

Tags: firebug, breakpoints

I've started using the Break On Next feature in Firebug (both in the Script and HTML tabs) and it's very useful. The only problem is when I click the button I need to navigate my mouse round the page like a [steady hand game](http://p.lefux.com/61/20100804/A1855000BO/hand-buzz-wire-game-wand-1-Gallay.jpg) to get to the correct element, so the correct mutation/script gets fired. This is pretty tiresome, and sometimes it's impossible if there are whole-page events or similar.

What would be really useful is a keyboard shortcut so the mouse can be position over/next to the relevant element, then Break On Next is executed, then the page is frozen as soon as the mouse is moved.

I've looked at the Firebug docs and done some Googling but to no avail. Does anyone know if this is possible and/or coming? Seems like an obvious feature, and perhaps an oversight at present (although Firebug is otherwise one of the best tools evar...).

Am running FireBug 1.9.1 on FF12.

**UPDATE:** courtesy of Sebastian Zartner, a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) has been introduced which will appear in Firebug 1.10a8: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5044#c4

Code here: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/commit/9a0f74c622df7f5faccaa7c59b8c4ffa457e7d78

Note that Firebug must be focussed for the shortcut to work. There are other suggestions on the Google Code issue page as to how its behaviour could be further improved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There now is a hotkey, released in the 1.10 beta. It's *CTRL+ALT+B*. See [Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts)

You can download 1.10 beta on [their download page](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

This would be actually extremely useful for me as well, I'm having same issues. However to my knowledge it seems there isn't any:

http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/46730eb62ba22eef/971017e6df091386

Perhaps we should write in the thread to get more attention to the feature.

**Edit:**
Actually, there's an issue opened for this:
http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5044

Comment: I've added my comment. Hopefully the momentum will build up -- the issue's been open since December, so it's not that old. I'm surprised more people aren't clambouring for it though!